# Stop Firefox playing linked MP4's

Tags: firefox, video

I still want Firefox to be able to play embedded MP4 videos, but when I click on a link to a video I want to get the "what do you want to do with this file?" dialog instead of Firefox starting to play the video.

I came across [this result](https://jdrch.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/how-to-prevent-firefox-from-playing-direct-link-mp4-files-in-the-browser/) on Google which says to go into `about:config` and change `media.windows-media-foundation.enable` to false, but that entry doesn't appear. I tried adding it and setting it to false, but it had no effect.

I tried changing `media.mp4.enabled` to false, that has the desired effect for clicking on links, but disables embedded videos too.

Comment: I am assuming you don't want to just right click and hit "save as"?

Comment: Also... what version of firefox are you on? media.windows-media-foundation.enable should be there... are you sure you arent just missing it?

Comment: Firefox 75 ... re: right click and save as, I'd actually like to get the "open this file in..." to play the video in VLC rather than permanently download it. windows-media-foundation definitely isn't there, I put it in the search bar and it only gave me the option to create it - which had no effect.

Comment: Try creating it as a Boolean and setting it to false....

Comment: Wait, are you on linux?